# Sound get distorted for MPMoviePlayerController and AVAudioPlayer when application kept idle for more than 48 hrs in IPOD

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipod, avaudiorecorder

I am working in IPOD App. Below points are main functionalities in this app
-  Audio recording or play (Using AVAudioRecorder for recording and AVAudioPlayer for play)
- Always  idle mode ON or guided access is ON/OFF
- Play video using MPMoviePlayerController(not Streaming Video)
- Pitch detection uses below link and it is active throw out the application and detects the sound frequency per second
 https://github.com/irtemed88/PitchDetector 
My difficulties/Questions  is ...

if device is in a idle mode and  guided access is ON without any user interaction for 48 hours then below issues occurred in IPOD
- The movie player in the app plays the video but without sound or distortion in it.
- while playing the recorded message which has same sound distortion.

I did refer the below StachOverFlow link which is similar to my difficulties but there is no update on it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734295/avaudiorecorder-memory-leak

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if there is any memory leak generated in the specified duration.
You can create a background task for every 24 hours ( assuming your video and audio plays properly for 24 hours) and then reallocate your recorder and player objects and then test the app.